# Is it good idea to horizontally partition groups of disks into different ZFS vdevs?

Tags: partitioning, zfs

```
 ---------------------------  +-------+ --------
                              |       |
                              | part  | vdev 1
                              |       | no redundancy
 ------------------ +-------+ +-------+ --------
                    |       | |       | vdev 2
                    | part  | | part  | mirroring
                    |       | |       | (2 mirrors)
 -------- +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ --------
          |       | |       | |       | vdev 3
          | part  | | part  | | part  | mirroring
          |       | |       | |       | (3 mirrors)
+-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ --------
|       | |       | |       | |       | vdev 4
| part  | | part  | | part  | | part  | raidz2
|       | |       | |       | |       | 
+-------+ +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ -------
   Disk      Disk      Disk      Disk
   1TB       2TB       3TB       4TB
```

Say I have a bunch of disks of different sizes and want to partition them to make use of all available space while aggregating the partitions into vdevs with different degrees of redundancy.

I am thinking of a ladder-like structure like the one depicted above.

Each disk 1 to 4, is split into 1,2,3 or 4 partitions respectively, 1TB in size.
Each disk is shared across 1,2,3 or 4 vdevs respectively.

- vdev 1 is dedicated to non-critical data (no redundancy)
- vdev 2 contains data which are duplicated once
- vdev 3 holds critical data, which are duplicated twice by means of 3 mirrors
- vdev 4 holds critical data, which are duplicated twice, using double parity. This should have the same reliability as vdev 3 but is more space efficient.

Given that I don't have a clear idea of how ZFS lays out the data internally, I am wondering if slicing a disk amongst several vdevs would be common practice or nonsense, performance and robustness-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is going to be attrocious the moment you access more than one of those pools simultaneously.

3-way mirroring is something you are unlikely to see much benefit from, other than wasting disk space.

RAIDZn has approximate IOPS performance of a single disk.

In terms of robustness, be careful because losing any but the smallest drive will will degrade multiple pools. Degraded state comes with a performance hit.

Also consider your overhead. You have 10TB of disks but 5TB of usable space of which 1TB has no redundancy.

You would probably be better off with an arrangement where you have two pools, a 2+3 and 4+1 and use sanoid/syncoid to regularly (hourly) snapshot and transfer the data from the 2+3 pool primary pool to the 4+1 backup pool. That still gives you 5TB of usable space, all of which is backed up, with a much less contorted setup.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but there are a couple of points I can't understand: when using raidz1 (i.e. raid 5) with three disks and writing onto two disks, the third disk will be a vdev juggling to write parity codes for the other two vdevs at once. Wouldn't this be affecting the performances similar to my case (accessing two vdevs which ends up on the same disk)? Also, it is true that I have 5TB of usable space, of which 1 has no redundancy. But there are 3 GB of that space which have a _double_ redundancy, where I would put the important stuff.